# VS 2017: fail to create C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++14

I have VS 2015 already running. Just installed VS 2017, but I fail to create C++ projects.
I get the following error:

```
The "CL" rule is missing the "ConformanceMode" property
```

[image]

I see that in the project properties in 'platform toolset' I get "v141 (not installed)":

[image]

and in VS 2017 installation I see that v141 toolset is installed:

[image]

I have already try to repair and to re-install VS 2015 and VS 2017.

Regards,
G.

Comment: Install SDK 8.1 and see if toolset v140 works normally.

Comment: @seccpur: The platform toolset isn't part of the SDK. And why the 8.1 SDK anyway? What does it offer over the current SDK?

Comment: Some app developed with v141 works alright under windows 10 but fails with windows 7, so a check is better. SDK 8.1 preferred for win7 & 8 IMHO

Comment: @seccpur: 8.1 SDK already installed. Toolset v140 works normally. But stil v141 does not work

Comment: @Mr.G: Which OS are you testing the executable with 10.xxx framework ? Test it in windows 10

Comment: @seccpur: I'm using windows 10. SDK 8.1 + SDK 10 installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved:

Remove the (user) environment variable: `VCTargetsPath`

Comment: Thank you so much.